# FlatList onEndReached for top of component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I would like to remove my "Load more" button from my application and implement a "inifinite-scroll" type of feature, which allows users to scroll up through their message history and download older messages as they're requested.

I'm moving to the FlatList component due to ListView being depricated and I'm trying to figure out a nice implementation for determining when the user has scrolled to the top of the page. Due to the fact that a FlatList always starts at the top of the list, we want to make sure to only call `onTopReached` when the user is scrolling through the list.

How can I go about this?

**Links to open-sourced implementations will be appreciated, but should be listed as a comment and not an answer. Implementations using the ListView are irrelevant.**

Comment: It's need to clarify to answer this: you want when user scroll to the start of the list to land more datas ? Like after bounce effect ?

Comment: @Ludovic Correct, like in a messaging application. Perhaps I'm overthinking it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use refresh control for this purpose.
You can do it similar to this

```
<FlatList
  data={feedList}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl refreshing={isloading} onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />
  }
/>
```